# Syntax error when passing an array to a method

Tags: vb6

I have created and array which will store the value of the inputbox, it is saying i have a syntax error and i am unsure how to fix it.

I have used parameter passing which i will display below also

```
Dim name() As String

For counter = 1 To 5
Call enter_questionnaire_data(name())    '2.0
Next
End sub
```

2nd sub-routine

```
Private Sub enter_questionnaire_data(ByRef name())

name() = InputBox("Enter the party name")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use name without brackets

```
Dim name As String
```

and in other method

```
Private Sub enter_questionnaire_data(ByRef name)
name = InputBox("Enter the party name")
```

Comment: He is calling `enter_questionnaire_data` inside a for loop. You can see that the functionality of the code is to input *multiple* names, hence the use of an array.

Answer (score 4):

why do you have `name` as a String array?

you just need to declare

```
Dim name As String
```

for allowing `name` to store a String

also you cannot assign values to array members like this

```
name() = InputBox("Enter the party name")
```

you need to specify the index also

EDIT: 
if you want string array to store the names, then

declare a static array of sufficient length

```
Dim name(10) As String
```

and use:

```
name(index) = InputBox("Enter the party name")
index = index+1;
```

where the index is incremented after every input till 10

(using dynamic array would be a bit complicated for you right now , so i am omitting dynamic array from discussion)

Comment: I need to use an array because the party name will be entered multiple times so i need an array to store the data for 'name'. How can i do this?

Comment: i have edited my answer to include your requirement. also you might like to check this link out for arrays http://patorjk.com/programming/tutorials/vbarrays.htm

Comment: The EDIT portion of your answer is a good solution. He should remember to call the sub with this line `Call enter_questionnaire_data(name)`, noting the lack of parentheses on name.

Answer (score 0):

About your program:

```
Dim name As String <---Without () you can use this for array 

For counter = 1 To 5
Call enter_questionnaire_data(name as string)<--- can you insert  variable/tipe
Next

End sub


Private Sub enter_questionnaire_data(name as string)

name = InputBox("Enter the party name")
```